# Magento soap api showing invalid api path

Tags: magento

I have created a web service but it is not running well showing invalid api path even though my identifiers which I have declared are correct.

Following is my code

testapi.php (Main file for hitting url)

```html
<?php
// custom api soap client example
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$myhellomsg = "<b>Helloworld Prashant</b>";
try {
$soap = new SoapClient('http://localhost:81/magento/api/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $soap->login('admin', '123456');
//echo "Login ID : $sessionId";
$result = $soap->call($sessionId, 'customapi.hello',array($myhellomsg));
echo $result;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Api.php file

```html
<?php
class Prashant_Customapi_Model_Helloworld_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
public function hello($msg) {
return "My Custom HelloWorld API In Magento. Here is Your Message ". $msg ;
}
}
```

api.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<api>
<resources>
<customapi translate="title" module="customapi">
<model>customapi/helloworld_api</model>
<title>Custom HelloWorld API </title>
<methods>
<hello translate="title" module="customapi">
<title>Prashant HelloWorld API</title>
<method>hello</method>
</hello>
</methods>
<faults module="customapi">
<data_invalid>
<code>100</code>
<message>Invalid data</message>
</data_invalid>
</faults>
</customapi>
</resources>
</api>
</config>
```

If anything else needed please let me know.